# Python - Read all files in a folder and create unique output for each file

Tags: python, directory

I'm trying to split two huge source files (with corresponding content in each line) into several smaller files with each containing unique input but so far, things have been off. I was thinking to have a method read all files in an  output directory and join their content into a certain blacklist. So at first, this blacklist is empty as the files are empty and I want to read the source file and copy `n` lines into the first smaller file and add the content to the blacklist. Next, I'm checking the list and write lines to the second file `n` times only if they're not on said blacklist. For some reason, I am not getting any input to the blacklist after I appended what was read the first time.
Here's what I got:

```
def check_overlap(path):
# check if lines appear in other files

    content = []
    for filename in os.listdir(path):
        with open(path + filename, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
            content.append(f.read())
            print(filename + str(content))
            # when I print this out, it's empty for the first file
            # the other 3 files have the desired output, but why?
            # How is it empty after I appended the content of f?
            f.close()

    all_content = "".join(content)
    return all_content


def shuffle_data(n, source, output):
# shuffle source into n portions while keeping each line unique

    with open(output, "w", encoding="utf-8") as shuffled_file:

        existing_files = check_overlap()

        with open(source, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as source:
            i = 0
            for line in source:
                if i < n and line not in existing_files:
                    shuffled_file.write(line)
                    i += 1

shuffle_data(50, "source1", "output_50A")
shuffle_data(50, "source2", "output_50B")
shuffle_data(200, "source1", "output_200A")
shuffle_data(200, "source2", "output_200B")
```

This also means I'm getting the wrong output overall. The sources look like this:

```
File 1    File 2
dog       dogs
book      books
horse     horses
flower    flowers
egg       eggs
```

And they have to keep their corresponding lines but because of the error I'm getting:

```
Output 1    Output 2
dog         dogs
book        books
horse       flowers
flowers     eggs
```

So it seems to be skipping random lines because of the wonky blacklist. The sources are randomized everytime I run the program so it's always different at which line they start to diverge. All output files are in the same directory, sources are in a different one.

Comment: Can you take a step back from the details, and explain what you're trying to accomplish? It seems like you want to break your input files into a pieces of a certain length? If so, there's a unix utility for that, [`split`](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/usplit.htm#syntax)

Comment: I have two files I want to break each into say 50 lines for one smaller file and 200 lines for another smaller file. but for the 200 I don't want any lines being repeated from the 50 lines file hence why I tried to create a blacklist and only put in lines that aren't present in previous files. The amount of lines per smaller file varies.

Comment: How long are the input files? 250 lines, or something else?

Comment: about 90.000, needs to yield 18 files for me

Comment: That's 5,000 lines per file, average. How's it going to work?

Comment: Portions are of different sizes: 50, 100, 200, 600, 1000, 3000, 10000 etc and I don't need to use every last line of the source as long as the portions are filled (there's bound to be leftovers but that's ok)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments, try something like this. You may need to handle exceptions if the source files run out before the sizes do.

```
Sizes = [50, 100, 200, 600, 1000, 3000, 10000]


with open('file1') as f1:
    with open('file2') as f2:
        sources = iter(zip(f1, f2))

        for size in Sizes:
            o1_name = 'output_{}A'.format(size)
            o2_name = 'output_{}B'.format(size)
            with open(o1_name, 'w') as o1:
                with open(o2_name, 'w') as o2:
                    for _ in range(size):
                        l1,l2 = next(sources)
                        o1.write(l1.strip())
                        o2.write(l2.strip())
```